# Django Nested Relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm not sure if I just can't concentrate or what, but I feel like this should be easy to do. I have 2 models, one that references the other as a simple foreign key relation (one-to-many) now in the template I want to display this relation as a nested unordered lists.

Comment: Maybe give a bit more info on what you are stuck on exactly.  You can't figure out how to retrieve the model objects you need from the database?   Or you have them already, but you just aren't sure how to display the data in a template?

Comment: Code samples help a lot.  The vague description is hard to follow.  Please provide code samples so we can understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not *quite* sure what you mean, but perhaps:

```
<ul>
    {% for foo in foo_list %}
    <li>
        {{ foo }}
        <ul>
            {% for bar in foo.bar_set.all %}
            <li>{{ bar }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
<ul>
```

Obviously, foo_list must be in the context, and bar has a foreign key relation to foo with no related_name.

Comment: AH! Exactly what I was looking for! - sorry for not providing code excerpts. Thank you.